# Base64 URL encode

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

My question for today is:

Is there a way to encode a http:// in base64 that will work in "a href=" and act like a link in a html email message (to avoid my newsletter email messages beeing blocked since I am using a link inside)?
I tried something below but it doesnt takes me to the desired URL when I click "go".

aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29t = google.com

```
<a href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29t">go</a>
```

Any tips? Thank you in advance.

Comment: no, if links are blocked - html client basically removes `<a>` tags from message

Comment: Usually the emails arent arriving at all. But when I'm trying with a different url.. it works.. so I'm guessing that url is blocked. Is there a work-around?